# Correlation among data - suggestions

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I would like to have your help for (simple) correlation problems. I've data about the measurement of some substances in the organs of animals (more than 20 samples).My data are obtained by different sources (journal articles, report, etc)

I need to check the presence of the correlation among different data. For example:

"*Calcium content in a x organ*" - "*calcium content in bones"*

or with **ratios** between two organs

"*Size of the liver*" - "*Calcium in bones/Calcium in a x organ **ratios***"

Could I use the Pearson method to check the correlation in both examples ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wouldn't be able to use correlations via Pearson's method. That said, you may want to consider a multivariate approach such as principle component analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The Pearson correlation measures linear correlation only. You should do a scatterplot of your data (eg. Calcium content in an organ as x-axis and calcium content in bones as y-axis) and see if the points seem to be falling in a straight line. If they do, then Pearson is appropriate. If they fall in a pattern that's not straight, then you may want to consider regression.